I'm using version 17 of Angular and I would like to know how to use CanActivate, which has been discontinued and is now CanActivateFn
I have the following code in my old version of Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from 
'@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AutorizacaoService } from '../services/autorizacao.service';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AutorizadoGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
   private autorizadoService: AutorizacaoService,
   private routerService: Router
 ){}

canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | 
boolean | UrlTree {
const usuarioEstaLogado = this.autorizadoService.obterLoginStatus();
  if (usuarioEstaLogado)
   return true;
  this.routerService.navigate(["/login"]);  
  return false;
 }

}

how do I reuse the same code structure, but adapting it to the new version and also using CanActivateFn?

yes, both @Inject and inject() work on dependency injection. It looks at the dependency tree, and gets the appropriate instance of what you are looking for

When you want to upgrade to canActivateFn. Just keep these points in mind.

The function is executed and destroyed, so there is no state (properties of the main class), so you should create a service to maintain state and share between canActivate executions.

Where you usually use a constructor private someService: SomeService cannot be done in a canActivateFn, so you should use the inject pattern, which is private someService = inject(SomeService);


Converted Code:
import { Component, inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  CanActivateFn,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  UrlTree,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AutorizadoService {
  obterLoginStatus() {
    return true; // fake code
  }
}

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
):
  | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
  | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
  | boolean
  | UrlTree => {
    const autorizadoService = inject(AutorizadoService);
    const router = inject(Router);
    const usuarioEstaLogado = autorizadoService.obterLoginStatus();
    if (usuarioEstaLogado) {
      return true;
    } else {
      router.navigate(["/login"]);  
      return false;
    }
};


injection would be dependency injection? @Naren Murali

Did you make this tokenService class just as an example? Could I put it in an external folder called service? @Naren Murali

My only doubt at the moment is about this typescript syntax in which I'm a beginner, what would be "?" and ":", did you perform an equal condition structure in my first code? @Naren Murali

ok, I'll look into it, could you just replace this ternary condition and do it with normal if? Please, what would it look like with normal if? @Naren Murali

I'm having trouble where to put the word inject when it comes to the standard if @Naren Murali

@vinudev it should be near the top, before you use the service, also prefer createUrlTree, it will be more useful than navigate, since it replaces the URL instead of navigating to new route.

After pasting the code into vscode I am getting an error in else "eclaration or statement expected." and in this "Object is possibly 'undefined'" @Naren Murali

How do I send a screenshot here in the comment? @Naren Murali

image added! @Naren Murali

the error persists, but this time only in else, I updated the image @Naren murali

It worked, thank you, now I have an error in my login.component, I need to import my autorizacao.service and when putting it in imports the following error persists "Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.( -992012)" From what I understand, I am unable to import the service because it is not standalone @Naren Murali

in the app.config.ts file? @Naren Murali

@vinudev you can add @Injectable(providedIn: 'root'}) export class AutorizadoService so that is provided throughout the application, no need to add to providers array. You can also add to either component providers array, app.config.ts also. But you should checkout the angular official documentation in https://angular.dev to get your angular journey off to a good start

After doing this, just inject it into login.component.ts, correct?  private authorizationService = inject(AutorizacaoService)  @Naren Murali
